# Limit of Integral of Matrix Exponential

Tags: matrices, integration, limits

I've been trying to evaluate

$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{t'=0}^t e^{-\mathbf{L}(t-t')}yu(t')dt'$

where $\mathbf{L}$ is the graph Laplacian, $y$ is a vector (that doesn't depend on $t'$) and $u(t)$ is the unit step function. This expression is found in the "Methods" section of the following paper

http://genome.cshlp.org/content/18/12/1991.long

and it evaluates to

$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} s\frac{1}{s}(s\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{L})^{-1}b = \mathbf{L}^{-1}b.$

I thought I could use the Laplace transform to get their answer, but I've been having trouble dealing with the $e^{-\mathbf{L}t}$ term in the integrand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of having the unit step function in the integral? Isn't it just 1?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is just 1 - I don't think having it in the integral makes too much of a difference in the end.